# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [nan 40]'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer

This is extremely odd. I practically did nothing with the app. Just fixed a constraint and the app loaded just fine and the constraint had taken the effect. Then simply I re-ran the app and got this error. Don't know how to fix it.

```html
First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea2673b __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010da1b735 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ea26595 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef8a923 _ZN2CA5Layer12set_positionERKNS_4Vec2IdEEb + 141
    4   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef79a13 -[CALayer setPosition:] + 57
    5   QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef7a16f -[CALayer setFrame:] + 561
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117ebf09e -[UIView(Geometry) setFrame:] + 336
    7   List24                              0x000000010d0c4364 $S6List2414ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtF + 836
    8   List24                              0x000000010d0c46bb $S6List2414ViewControllerC05tableB0_12cellForRowAtSo07UITableB4CellCSo0iB0C_10Foundation9IndexPathVtFTo + 155
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000117d38c1c -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 771
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117d391a9 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] + 73
    11  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117d002aa -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] + 2863
    12  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117d20f62 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 165
    13  UIKitCore                           0x0000000117ede749 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1441
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef80299 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 175
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef85153 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 395
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010eefdbb2 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 342
    17  QuartzCore                          0x000000010ef34e62 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 576
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00000001177e1208 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 139
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e98a2bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e989a70 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 336
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e9842e4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1284
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e983aa1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001142531dd GSEventRunModal + 62
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00000001177c6a4f UIApplicationMain + 140
    25  List24                              0x000000010d0d0f27 main + 71
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011116dced start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: remove the constraint and check the crash

Comment: @vivekDas I have removed the whole view of which I was changing the constraint - still getting that crash. Extremely weird.

Comment: do u hav UITableView ? check the cell creation

Comment: Yes I do! Should I check the constraints within custom cell file?

Comment: yes, right check custom cell

Comment: @vivekDas Absolutely no issue with it. I tried commenting out some constraints and CGRect() stuff but still getting the error.

Comment: can u add your code of table view

Comment: @vivekDas I just quit xcode and ran the project again and it's working now. I have no idea how it has started working lol